# Python: Deep merging of two JSON objects

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to build a single JSON object from several in Python with two generations.

```
lineage1 = {"name":"rob", "children":[{"name":"henry", "children":[{"name":"johnny", "age":5}]}]}
lineage2 = {"name":"rob", "children":[{"name":"henry", "children":[{"name":"susan", "age":3}]}]}
lineage3 = {"name":"rob", "children":[{"name":"shannon", "children":[{"name":"casey", "age":13}]}]}
lineage4 = {"name":"rob", "children":[{"name":"shannon", "children":[{"name":"alfred", "age":9}]}]}
```

I want to collect around (grandfather, (parents, (children)).  E.g.

```
glin = {"name":"rob","children":[{"name":"henry", "children":[{"name":"johnny", "age":5},{"name":"susan", "age":3}]}, {"name":"shannon", "children":[{"name":"casey", "age":13},{"name":"alfred", "age":9}]}]}
```

Is there a slick, pythonic way to do this?  This will be executed in a streaming fashion, as record come in I'd like to merge them to the "master" json.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: save it in database - this will be most efficient way )

Comment: @madzohan Adding I/O is generally not a way to improve efficiency.

Comment: @ChrisMartin this is from question 'This will be executed in a streaming fashion, as record come in I'd like to merge them to the "master" json'

Comment: @madzohan I'll rephrase: Adding *more* I/O is generally not a way to improve efficiency.